# Eclipse CDT open declaration of auto type variable

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, declaration, auto

With [Eclipse CDT](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) one can use "Open Declaration" to goto the declaration of a class, function, ... . This function can be accessed by the shortcut key `F3`.

If one hovers with the mouse over `auto` in code looking like this

```
const auto A = getA();
```

eclipse resolves the type of `A`. A popup displays the correct type. Nevertheless, one can not use `F3` to goto the declaration of the type of `A`.

Can eclipse be configured to activate this?
I'm using C++ 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has [recently been implemented](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=511522). It's available in Eclipse Oxygen (released June 2017) and later.

Comment: @AlexGidan: Please give a complete code example. Probably easiest to do so in a new question (you can link to it from a comment here).